# How would a strong humanoid heal from muscle injury

Tags: science-based, biology, humans

## Background info

The humanoids in my Kepler Bb story have stronger muscles at every stage. This makes it much easier for babies to go through physical milestones and thus the shortening of time before reaching any given physical milestone. Communication also is sped up. However the eating milestones are slowed down.

### Milestones

Newborn: none

3 months: sitting without support, saying single words

6 months: standing, saying phrases and short sentences

9 months: walking, questioning, fruits and veggies

12 months: running and jumping, normal communication

etc.

### Why stronger?

Stronger muscles are easier to develop than bigger muscles, especially if it is genetic like in these humanoids.

### Muscle injuries and their effects

1st degree arm muscle injury:

very sore for most movements(most movements somehow involve the arms, even laying down)

1st degree chest muscle injury:

No heavy lifting

1st degree abdominal muscle injury:

Not much for normal movements, Exercise hurts

1st degree back muscle injury:

A lot of pain on all fours, Breach birth vaginally is much worse.

1st degree leg muscle injury:

Similar to arm muscle injury

2nd degree arm muscle injury:

Can't move much

2nd degree chest muscle injury:

Strength drastically decreased

2nd degree abdominal muscle injury:

abdominal pressure from movement of abdominal organs

2nd degree back muscle injury:

bad balance

2nd degree leg muscle injury:

Similar to arm muscle injury

3rd degree muscle injury:

Complete immobility of that part, surgery is absolutely needed.

Injury of multiple muscles:

Loss of strength

### Muscle injury -> Muscle growth?

The way I designed these humanoids, muscle injury leads to muscle growth more than just muscle soreness. The only exception is 3rd degree muscle injury. This conserves muscle mass.

Now the way I see it, this requires a special organ or part of an organ specialized for protein storage.

How else could they grow muscles or conserve muscle mass from injury without causing protein deficiency everywhere else including their 2 hearts and circulatory systems?

Comment: Why don't you just make them eat more and give them a better metabolism?

Comment: Well I could except for one problem. What if their arms are too sore for them to eat normally? I know that I have been told that the less you use an injured muscle the more stiff it gets but there is always a chance of further injury and with second degree muscle injury, it is more likely to go to third degree than a first degree muscle injury is to go to second degree. It also depends on how the muscle was injured(whether it was from a fracture, a severe burn, overexertion, or some other cause of muscle injury)

Comment: You don't have to eat using your arms. You can face plant into your plate of food similar to when people have those pie eating contests. You can also hire somebody to feed you. If you really have to, you can blend your food and drink it. There are many ways to get around sore muscle problems.

Comment: How about putting some indication of what the question is at the top, followed by story details?  Personally, I've had severe problems on SE with detailed explainations leading up to a proper topic sentence, and that's when it's in the first paragraph! And, the Title doesn't count.

Comment: Having a special organ to store proteins in advance of use makes no sense. The body would still need to move the proteins to the site of use; why not just build the proteins on the spot where they need to be used... which is what every living thing does? As Aify said, just "dial up" the metabolic rate for faster healing, if you think that's necessary. Of course, with a higher metabolic rate they need to eat more per day, and realistically they'd have a shorter lifespan. But a faster reflexes and possibly faster thinking, so... "Live fast, die young!"

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use things like protein-tablets or even soluble protein packs? For 1st degree muscle injuries, or general soreness, an edible tablet jam-packed with protein that is biologically treated to target that specific injured/sore area, and fix it. There are certain proteins that know exactly where to go around the body, for example a protein mentioned in Alex Rider: Scorpia, that acts like a heat-seeking missile and goes immediately to the heart. But then again a heart is a heart, it's the same in every human body. But a specific muscle that is injured or sore may be more difficult to target.

Thus, soluble protein packs may work, where a pad attached to a protein pack can be stuck onto the skin above the sore muscle. The pad itself could contain an agent that momentarily allows protein molecules to be absorbed by the skin as long as the pad is in contact with the skin cells. Then the protein pack would release its cargo into the skin, and the protein will travel down to the muscle and patch it up. The pad can then be removed, with no other effects or residue on the skin. I guess, something like [tigerbalm patches](http://www.tigerbalm.com/sg/symptoms/11/symptoms_products/6). Of course, in tigerbalm, medicine is absorbed by the skin and pulled down to the muscle. In your case, it would be protein molecules, which may be tricker...

Comment: Yeah it might be trickier to have protein be absorbed by the skin and migrated to the muscles since protein is needed for every cell in the body, whether that be the actin and myosin in muscles, the pepsin in the stomach, or the melanin in the skin.

Comment: @Caters hmmm point taken... Maybe then the pad itself could have a solution that inhibits the skin cells from absorbing the protein temporarily?

Answer (score 1):

Everything might be doubled up as in your heart scenario.

So an injured arm exterior could be shed to reveal the awaiting / backup arm.

A new arm would grow underneath.

Alternatively there could be different dimensions based on phase. Looking at the space inside an atom its not impossible that an alternative out of phase matrix could exist in parallel without taking up any additional space.